# How to import defined variable from raw_input in an imported file?

Tags: macos, python-2.7, atom-editor

I am fairly new to coding, and am currently learning my first language (python) using the book "Learn Python the Hard Way" but this is not a specific exercise in the book and I am just practicing while I am reading code for Exercise 23 and am currently am just trying to figure out if this is even possible...

**My first file is pr1.py:**

```
def func():
    a = float(raw_input("Enter Your Age:"))
    b = float(raw_input("Enter Your Weight:"))
    c = float(raw_input("Enter Your Height:"))

age = "a"
weight = "b"
height = "c"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("This is pr1.py")

else:
    print("%s is being imported to another file") % __name__
```

**My second file is pr2.py**

```
import pr1

def func():
    x = raw_input("Enter Your Race:")
    y = raw_input("Enter Your Gender:")
    z = raw_input("Enter Your Language:")

print "Lets find your numbers"
pr1.func()

print "Lets find your identity"
func()

race = "x"
gender = "y"
language = "z"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("This is pr2.py")

else:
    print("%s is being imported into another file") % __name__
```

**This is my 3rd file pr3.py**

```
import pr1

print "%s = a %s = b %s = c" % (age, weight, height)

import pr2

print "%s = x, %s = y, %s = z" % (race, gender, language)
```

When I run pr3.py and comment out the scripts to "print" line 3 and line 7 this is what i get:

```
python pr3.py
pr1 is being imported to another file
Lets find your numbers
Enter Your Age:25
Enter Your Weight:224
Enter Your Height:76
Lets find your identity
Enter Your Race:white
Enter Your Gender:male
Enter Your Language:english
pr2 is being imported into another file
```

and I am expecting the pr3.py file to print those statement's with the previously defined variable's.

but instead it comes up with this error:

```
pr1 is being imported to another file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pr3.py", line 3, in <module>
    print "%s = a %s = b %s = c" % (age, weight, height)
NameError: name 'age' is not defined
```

Now when I run my last file in the command, I am expecting it to import the previous 2 files, so I can input the data I put into raw_input, and then use use it in other files... but it seems like once both files get imported and I input the data into their respective raw_input's, it seems as if the pr3.py forget's the raw input and their corresponding variable's.

Please forgive me if I am totally lacking some obvious knowledge that could fix all this, but I am very new to coding and not even a month ago, I didn't even know you could create a directory in the terminal.

Thank's for reading and I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, here are a couple of things.
First I will say which obvious things are wrong with your code.
After that I will show you an example of your code, using classes.

So, first:
`age, weight, height` are all defined in `pr1.py`, so eiter you need to refer to them as `pr1.age, pr1.weight, pr1.height`, or you `from pr1 import age, weight, height`. Same applies for `race, gender, language` in `pr2.py`
That said, you might expect to get what you inputted to be printed out. But you only assigned the characters `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, `'x'`, `'y'` and `'z'` to those variables.
Also you print `age, weight and height` before you even run `func()` in `pr2.py`

So second: how do we fix this. First you need to think about in which order things are happening, when you do imports. Also you need to think about, if the variables you refer to, really are set anywhere.
In this case you set your `raw_input`'s to variables insde a function, and they will only be accessible inside that function.
This can be fixed by using globals, or by making an object. I will reccommend using object (classes).
Since you say you are fairly new to programming, classes might seem over your head now, but when you get it, it solves alot of these problems.
Also you will get to classes soon enough in [Learn Python The Hard Way](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/) soon enough.

To take your code as example:

pr1.py:

```
class Numbers:

    def func(self):
        self.age = float(raw_input("Enter Your Age:"))
        self.weight = float(raw_input("Enter Your Weight:"))
        self.height = float(raw_input("Enter Your Height:"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("This is pr1.py")

else:
    print("%s is being imported to another file") % __name__
```

pr2.py:

```
from pr1 import Numbers

class Identity:

    def func(self):
        self.race = raw_input("Enter Your Race:")
        self.gender = raw_input("Enter Your Gender:")
        self.language = raw_input("Enter Your Language:")


print "Lets find your numbers"
nrs = Numbers()
nrs.func()

print "Lets find your identity"
ids = Identity()
ids.func()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("This is pr2.py")

else:
    print("%s is being imported into another file") % __name__
```

pr3.py:

```
from pr2 import *

print "%s = a %s = b %s = c" % (nrs.age, nrs.weight, nrs.height)

print "%s = x, %s = y, %s = z" % (ids.race, ids.gender, ids.language)
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time for the in depth explanation, that really helped alot!

Comment: @Niles you are wellcome.